# how to add .a file in my xcode

Tags: iphone

how can i add .a file in my xcode

Answer (score 2):

Project menu > Add to Project... (or <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> if that's how you roll)

Answer (score 1):

You can also drag/drop your file from the finder in your XCode project.